# Block access from countries in azure b2c

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

we have currently the challenge to block access to our whole b2c services for several countries.
I tried to setup a conditional access rule to block specific countries, but it does not applied on normal application sign ins.
This will block my admin account to login to azure portal, but not the users to sign in to saml or openid connected applications.

What would be the correct way to implement it? In Custom Policies with Transformations?

Comment: see: https://cloudcompanyapps.com/2019/04/18/block-users-by-location-in-azure-o365/

Comment: Hi @CarlZhao, as I wrote I already created a conditional access policy with block countries. But they are not used in Azure B2C for application sign ins of the users. The conditional access does not affect the b2c policies.

Comment: Hi @Wyphorn Can you Please provide us more details what process did you followed(to reproduce the issue as you are stating its not working).? are you using built in flow or custom policies? What do you mean by it does not affect the b2c policies? if you are using custom polciies, please share the policy configuration.